# Mindsensor Motor Multiplexer jump on run_unlimited

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, not-exactly-c

I am trying to run a nxt motor using the mindsensors motor multiplexer at a slow speed.  When I turn it on, it tends to jump approx 20 to 40 degrees before moving at a slow speed.  Has anyone seen this behavior?

I am using NXT 1.0 with firmware down loaded from `lms_arm_mindsensors_129.rfw`.  Sample code in NXC (I am using Bricx Command Center as my IDE) is as follows:

```
MMX_Run_Degrees (SensorPort, Addr, MMX_Motor_2, MMX_Direction_Reverse,
     MMX_Speed_Slow, 220, MMX_Completion_Wait_For, MMX_Next_Action_Brake);
Wait(500);

MMX_Run_Unlimited( SensorPort, Addr, MMX_Motor_2,MMX_Direction_Forward, 5);
// The jump happens here.
while(Sensor(IN_2)< SENSORTHRESHOLD);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this behaviour using the NxtMMX with the EV3 (while writing the driver for ev3dev). I am fairly certain that this is the speed regulation PID overshooting and then slowing down. In NXC you can use `MMX_SetPerformanceParameters` to change the PID parameters and possibly get rid of the overshoot.